# Store all combinations of String array and search

Tags: java, string, search, combinations

I have a big static dataset in the memory that stores the following attributes of people:

[sex, age, race, marital-status, education, native-country, workclass, occupation]

Each attribute takes values from a predefined set of values, and set is of different size for each attribute. This is the dictionary:

[[Male, Female], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100], [White, Asian-Pac-Islander, Amer-Indian-Eskimo, Other, Black], [Married-civ-spouse, Divorced, Never-married, Separated, Widowed, Married-spouse-absent, Married-AF-spouse], [Bachelors, Some-college, 11th, HS-grad, Prof-school, Assoc-acdm, Assoc-voc, 9th, 7th-8th, 12th, Masters, 1st-4th, 10th, Doctorate, 5th-6th, Preschool], [United-States, Cambodia, England, Puerto-Rico, Canada, Germany, Outlying-US(Guam-USVI-etc), India, Japan, Greece, South, China, Cuba, Iran, Honduras, Philippines, Italy, Poland, Jamaica, Vietnam, Mexico, Portugal, Ireland, France, Dominican-Republic, Laos, Ecuador, Taiwan, Haiti, Columbia, Hungary, Guatemala, Nicaragua, Scotland, Thailand, Yugoslavia, El-Salvador, Trinadad&Tobago, Peru, Hong, Holand-Netherlands], [Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Self-emp-inc, Federal-gov, Local-gov, State-gov, Without-pay, Never-worked], [Tech-support, Craft-repair, Other-service, Sales, Exec-managerial, Prof-specialty, Handlers-cleaners, Machine-op-inspct, Adm-clerical, Farming-fishing, Transport-moving, Priv-house-serv, Protective-serv, Armed-Forces]]

I would like to have a structure that keeps all possible combinations, so that for each combination in my dataset I can store some statistics (e.g. how many times a specific combination exists in the dataset), but store some information also for combinations that don't exist in the dataset. So all combinations should be represented.

I tried producing all possible combinations using ArrayList of String[] 
but it takes several seconds and then searching for a specific combination using indexOf(x), where x is String[] doesn't seem to work.

```
public class Grid  {

// Immutable fields
private final int combinationLength;
private final String[][] values;
private final int[] maxIndexes;
private final ArrayList<String[]> GridValues = new ArrayList<String[]>();
// Mutable fields
private final int[] currentIndexes;
private boolean hasNext;

public Grid(final String[][] array) {
    combinationLength = array.length;
    values = array;
    maxIndexes = new int[combinationLength];
    currentIndexes = new int[combinationLength];

    if (combinationLength == 0) {
        hasNext = false;
        return;
    }

    hasNext = true;


    // Fill in the arrays of max indexes and current indexes.
    for (int i = 0; i < combinationLength; ++i) {
        if (values[i].length == 0) {
            // Set hasNext to false if at least one of the value-arrays is empty.
            // Stop the loop as the behavior of the iterator is already defined in this case:
            // the iterator will just return no combinations.
            hasNext = false;
            return;
        }

        maxIndexes[i] = values[i].length - 1;
        currentIndexes[i] = 0;
    }

    while (hasNext()){
        String[] nextCombination = next();
        GridValues.add(nextCombination);
    }
}


private boolean hasNext() {
    return hasNext;
}


public String[] next() {
    if (!hasNext) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No more combinations are available");
    }
    final String[] combination = getCombinationByCurrentIndexes();
    nextIndexesCombination();
    return combination;
}

private String[] getCombinationByCurrentIndexes() {
    final String[] combination = new String[combinationLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < combinationLength; ++i) {
        combination[i] = values[i][currentIndexes[i]];
    }
    return combination;
}

private void nextIndexesCombination() {

    for (int i = combinationLength - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (currentIndexes[i] < maxIndexes[i]) {
            // Increment the current index
            ++currentIndexes[i];
            return;
        } else {
            // Current index at max: 
            // reset it to zero and "carry" to the next index
            currentIndexes[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    // If we are here, then all current indexes are at max, and there are no more combinations
    hasNext = false;
}
}
```

Anyone has an idea for a faster and better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any example code? It is really hard to understand what you want to do

Comment: There is only a specific number of ways to generate all combinations of the data you want. None are faster than the other. Why do you need this? And could you benefit from something like SQLite?

Comment: @Yazan My goal is to know how many times specific combinations exist in the dataset, but at the end I want to add some 'noise' and so also  those that don't exist will get a non-zero value

Comment: oh, sorry, i thought you wan to log the incoming search queries, i will delete my comments :)

Comment: A quick calculation tells me you have about half a billion combinations. You probably want to rethink what you're trying to do. If you generate statistics on demand it would be a lot more feasible, but pre-generating is not likely to work.

Comment: @shmosel you are absolutely right... I think it would be enough to represent combinations in some smart way and not produce them. But I dont have an idea so far.

Comment: @ikro All you've said is you want to "store some information also for combinations that don't exist in the dataset." Since we've established that's not feasible, you'll need to either change your requirements or be more specific about why you need this so we can look for an alternative solution.

Comment: @shmosel My goal is to know how many times all possible combinations exist in the dataset. Out of millions of possible combinations, of course most of them will not exist in the dataset, and so it will be zero count. But my algorithm requires that I put some noise, and zero values will get a positive value.  That means, some combinations that don't exist in the database will appear as if they exist.

Comment: @ikro How much "noise" do you require, and why?

Comment: @shmosel The noise will be added according to laplacian distribution later to all the combination counts (zero and non-zero).  This is for anonymization purposes.

Comment: @shmosel OK, I came up with a solution that doesn't require to produce all the combinations. Indeed it's not needed, as you pointed out from the beginning. Thanks for pointing to the right direction and for trying to understand more about the problem. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am making an assumption here- I am assuming the data does not keep changing (looking at the data does not feel like its dynamic).

I would use an a local file based HSQL DB to store the data (I chose this for speed purposes - however feel free to swap this out for a formal dB like MySQL).

The trick to get all the types counts across various dimensions is in the schema.
    For data mining "[Star Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)" is the preferred approach. This schema will allow you to group by, count on any dimension you want. In your case the schema would probably look like:

```
table person - columns(id (primary key), name, age, sex_id, country_id, highest_education_id, income)
table sex - columns(id (primary key), name)
table country - columns(id (primary key), name)
table education - columns(id (primary key), name)
```

This way if you want to find count of all people who are from Columbia, the query would be like:

```
select count(*) from people where country_id = <columbia country id>
```

You can do even higher order queries like, find a total income of all the japanese :

```
select country.name, sum(people.income)
from people inner join country on people.country_id = country.id
and country.name = "Japan"
```

Its highly flexible and extensible.